# serialize doubles in .net while retaining accuracy

Tags: .net, serialization, floating-point, double

I want to be able to save several arrays of doubles to a file. I don’t want to use the binary serializer as like this work in environments where this isn’t available (i.e. Silverlight/WP7). I’d like this to I thought about using text format, which is easy, but I’m worried I’ll use accuracy when the numbers are rounded to be printed. So is there a ‘correct’ way to serialize a double to a text or binary format and retain full accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use the "r" (roundtrip) specifier to convert the double to a string, or you could use [BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.doubletoint64bits.aspx) to convert the `double` to `long` (which I assume you're confident in serializing accurately) and then [`BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.int64bitstodouble.aspx) at the other end.

One problem - those methods aren't available in WP7. They're in desktop Silverlight though.

For Windows Phone 7 you could use [`BitConverter.GetBytes(double)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5be4sc9%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and [`BitConverter.ToDouble(byte[], int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.todouble%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) instead though.

Answer (score 2):

[`BinaryWrite.Write(double)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez8wcba9.aspx) can be used safely to write (and then read) double. So you can loop around the array write the doubles. But as Jon said, you can also use `BitConverter.GetBytes()` and manually write it.